# How to render MS-Word file with in any control of Universal Windows Platform (UWP) instead to open it in separate file?

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I'm new to `Universal Windows Platform (UWP)` and I'm trying to open some `word (.docx)` file inside the `UWP` app instead of opening it in a separate window of `MS Word` (as `PDF` file viewer already available in `UWP` app). I tried to look up the solution but the thing I found is just to open the file in a separate window. The code to open the file is:

```
private async void ShowWordFile()
{
    var file = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.GetFileAsync("My.docx");

    if (file != null)
    {
        // Launch the retrieved file
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchFileAsync(file);
    }
}
```

But I want to show the content of the file **as it is** in `UWP` application.**(I mean, I want `WORD Viewer` within `UWP`).**

Comment: There is no built-in Word viewer control available in UWP. Word files should be opened in MS Word.

Comment: Is there any possibility to get any `api`  in near future, if you'd confirm!! @mm8

Comment: Most probably not. Like I said, Word files are supposed to be opened in MS Word and not some custom app.